# Если первая колонка больше чем вторая, значение первой заменить на значение второй

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Как сделать, что бы в DataFrame, значение первой колонки заменить на значение второй колонки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы когда колонка installs меньше/раньше по дню, чем колонка serve_time, дата в колонке installs заменялась на дату в колонке server_time.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно что бы когда колонка installs меньше/раньше по дню, чем колонка
> serve_time, дата в колонке installs заменялась, на дату в колонке
> server_time.

Ну прямо вот буквально как написано - в тех строках, которые удовлетворяют условию, поменять вот это на вот то:

```
condition = df['installs'] < df['server_time']
df.loc[condition, 'installs'] = df.loc[condition, 'server_time']
```